# Which kind of physics does everything reduce to?

Tags: physicalism, reductionism

I don't know whether the proper term is Physicalism or Physical Reductionism (it's Reductive Physicalism--thank you, Conifold), but what I'm referring to is the position that everything reduces to physics.  My question is, for proponents of this doctrine (assuming there actually are any), which branch of physics does everything reduce to?  Quantum Mechanics?  Particle Physics?

The reason I ask is that not even all branches of physics reduce to one branch of physics.  With a few exceptions, different physical theories interlock and agree with one another in a pleasing way that reassures the student that it isn't all just BS.  For example, Newtonian mechanics can be seen as an approximation to relativistic mechanics for smallish amounts of energy.  This is what you'd hope for, since a theory that gave different results from Newtonian mechanics in everyday circumstances isn't likely to be right.  And it is also true that statistical mechanics, both the classical and quantum versions, give some insight into the results of thermodynamics by going down a level--the microscopic level of molecules.

However, it is not the case that thermodynamics *reduces* to statistical mechanics.  It is its own separate discipline based on generalizations from macroscopic empirical observations, and its validity does not depend on a particular microscopic statistical interpretation.  Even if some flaw is discovered in the statistical approach, it does not mean that the laws and results of thermodynamics are suddenly in doubt. The second law of thermodynamics doesn't go away just because nobody has figured out how to derive it as a theorem in statistical mechanics (That's probably not the most relevant example, since a lot of people are apparently satisfied that it has been, and it's not central to my point).  Also, as Conifold pointed out in the comments below, there is still a lack of conceptual reduction of thermodynamics to statistical mechanics. Thermodynamic concepts have to be imposed on the microscopic picture, rather than falling out naturally.

So when you look at what physical theories are actually like, you see that they are a bit more like a quilt than a perfectly nested set of Russian dolls.  Thus I'd like to know a bit more specifically what people have in mind when they say everything reduces to physics.

Comment: I think the idea is that the empirical laws we discover in physics will *eventually* be shown to be derivable from some fundamental theory. (At least as approximations, the way Newtonian gravity turns out to be an approximation to general relativity--wherever their predictions differ, general relativity is always found to be correct. Similarly I believe all the laws of thermodynamics are currently derivable from statistical mechanics, do you know any exceptions?) This idea of physical reductionism doesn't require that we be able to do that in practice *yet* given our current knowledge.

Comment: The proper term is reductive physicalism. As to what kind, there is an ideal of the fundamental "theory of everything" that all other scientific theories (in principle) reduce to. Ideally, on the model of thermodynamics and statistical mechanics. It is understood that this may not be achievable in practice (actually reducing quantum chemistry to quantum mechanics is prohibitively complex, but few doubt that it is possible), and what the "theory of everything" might look like is left open to future discovery, although rough contours of some candidates are sketched.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  "Similarly I believe all the laws of thermodynamics are currently derivable from statistical mechanics, do you know any exceptions?"  Well, the one I mentioned.  I am not aware that the SLOT is a theorem in statistical mechanics.  Maybe there has been progress that I don't know about.  I'm no expert.  It's not even clear to me that the law of conservation of energy in mechanics/statistical mechanics is as general as the first law of thermo.

Comment: The fact that a low-entropy state of an isolated system will tend to evolve into a higher-entropy state can be derived from statistical mechanics, though the overall fact that the entropy of the universe has been continually increasing--the "arrow of time" problem--is thought to depend on low-entropy boundary conditions near the Big Bang that aren't yet explained (but I think most physicists would bet that if we do get a final unified theory of fundamental physics and apply it to cosmology, it would explain this fact of low-entropy boundary conditions).

Comment: The second law follows from ergodicity assuming low entropy initial state of the universe, see [How do you prove the second law of thermodynamics from statistical mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81465/65263) A "theory of everything" is normally expected to account only for the acting laws, not accidents of initial conditions and their consequences. Although there may be a yet unknown law that explains why the Big Bang produced a low entropy state.

Comment: A theory-of-everything must be metaphysical, Physics is non-reductive by definition. . The phrase 'reductive physicalism' appears to be an oxymoron of the same kind as 'fundamental physics' and indicates scientism. The question is valid if it asks which part of physics is most-nearly fundamental, but the idea that everything reduces to physics is not in accord with logic and reason.  .

Comment: @Conifold  Okay, I will concede that something bearing a family resemblance to the 2nd Law of Thermo can be derived in statistical mechanics.  I think I distracted from my own main point by bringing that up.  And I understand what you and Hypnosifl are saying about the role of a possible ToE.  What I am questioning is the idea that all physical theories (much less all scientific theories) could be reduced to just one.  I get the idea that it would be nice to know the laws that govern whatever the smallest physical whatsits are, whether they turn out to be strings or something else...

Comment: ... And I get the idea that given such laws (together with some initial conditions) everything else *follows* in some sense.   What I'm claiming is that the sense in which everything else *follows* is useless.  If you wanted to know why a spinning heavy top behaves the way it does, would you get more insight into it by approaching it from string theory?  Would a theory of everything provide the "ultimate explanation" for macroscopic phenomena like that?  It seems to me that reduction only adds insight when taken one level at a time.

Comment: I think practical limitations of it, especially for explanatory value, are generally acknowledged. It is more of a proof-of-concept type of aspiration that plays into a particular metaphysical view of how the world is. There is a deeper limitation, that many philosophers pointed out, that even in the prototypical case of thermodynamics there is no *conceptual* reduction. Thermodynamical concepts (entropy, enthalpy, pressure, etc.) do not jump out of SM. They have to be imposed by hand, and only *then* can mathematical reduction of the laws be effected. So "everything" isn't everything.

Comment: @Conifold  That is an excellent point about concepts.  And now that you mention it, I can see that it is ubiquitous.  Even within a theory, like classical mechanics, concepts have to be imposed from outside in order for the theory to have any practical application.  There is nothing in Newton's laws of motion that leads directly to rigid bodies or perfect fluids.  But once those concepts are idealized from actual things in nature, the general laws of motion can be applied to them.

Comment: One question here, when you talk about everything reducing to some fundamental theory of physics, do you just mean that all *physical* facts can be derived from the fundamental theory (along with some initial conditions perhaps), or do you mean all facts of any kind whatsoever, including metaphysical ones, can be so reduced to fundamental physics? I think in philosophy [reductive physicalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/physicalism/#RedNonRedPhy) would refer to the latter, but there may be philosophers who would be inclined to accept the former but not the latter, like David Chalmers.

Comment: @Hypnosifl My question is aimed at Reductive Physicalism.  My strategy for challenging it is pointing out that even the much more plausible idea that all physics reduces to some one fundamental physical theory has issues.

Comment: So if we call the idea that all physical facts reduce to fundamental laws + initial conditions "scientific reductionism" (SR), and if we call the metaphysical view that all facts about reality whatsoever reduce to physical ones "reductive physicalism" (RP), you are saying that while SR could be true while RP is false (as in a Chalmers type view), RP depends on SR so by questioning SR you're calling RP into doubt as well? Not sure it's true you can't have RP without SR, one could argue for some kind of strong emergentism in physical world without any metaphysical facts diff. from physical ones.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Yes you've put my argument correctly.  Since I take physical facts to be a subset of all facts about reality whatsoever, I'm having a hard time understanding your last sentence.

Comment: The way I would understand "strong emergentism" in the purely physical realm (not about non-physical facts like qualia) would be some sort of idea that when you assemble certain configurations of fundamental particles, totally new laws may kick in that weren't in any way deducible from the more basic laws that apply to smaller (or more generic) configurations of particles. So for example there might be special laws of nature governing biological systems that are totally unlike the laws of fundamental particle physics. This sort of thing would violate SR but could be compatible with RP.

Comment: (and I agree physical facts are a subset of all possible facts about reality, I wasn't saying otherwise in the last sentence you were confused about, I was just saying one could believe 'the only facts about reality are physical facts' while denying the scientific reductionist view that all physical facts are derivable from bottom-level physical laws + initial conditions)

Comment: @Hypnosifl Oh, that is an interesting possibility I hadn't considered.  You're right, I suppose one could be a reductive physicalist without being a scientific reductionist.  Would you agree that reductive physicalists  have a strong tendency to be scientific reductionists?  By the way, the strong emergentist position for physics sounds not unreasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

They did work out how to express the laws of thermodynamics using statistical mechanics. What you are talking about is unification in physics. Temperature for instance was discovered to be a macroscopic consequence of microscopic degrees of freedom. Shannon while working on information transfer showed entropy is also a result of information change in a system.

Maxwell's equations unified electrical and magnetic phenomena. Special Relativity arose integrating the single speed of light from Maxwell's equations with Newton's. Until electromagnetism, nuclear decay, and nuclear structures, all got neatly wrapped up in one structure, Quantum Field Theory. That is our best theory. And General Relativity is likely going to get integrated through looking at information flow.

John Wheeler made probably the strongest statement how that might look with his 'It From Bit' doctrine:

> "Every it – every particle, every field of force, even the space-time continuum itself _ derives its function, its meaning, its very existence entirely... from the apparatus-elected answers to yes or no questions, binary choices, bits." - quoted from [here](https://plus.maths.org/content/it-bit-0) which has far more info

On the other hand, Hawking concluded late in his career [a truly unified theory of all physics could be impossible](http://www.hawking.org.uk/godel-and-the-end-of-physics.html).

Given that structures as important for making predictions as are atoms, namely brains, are emergent we can interpret reductionism as fundamentally limited.

Abstraction and simplification, are simply how minds work. We have to make things tractable. I don't see unification as truly reductionism, but as translatability, interoperability between different modes of description. Very often something complex like a brain is irreducible in practice, it is vastly complex. But we have no reason to think it's made of more than atoms, and when we really 'understand' them we will have efficient abstractions (that's what understanding is). So I expect unification to reach quantum-gravity, probably with deeper insights into information that look like It-From-Bit. But that won't be the end of it anymore than understanding a cell explains the brain. But the things we experience are in one language, information, what Galileo meant when he said mathematics is the language of God. It is experience that unifies, by translating and connecting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the linked articles!  Wheeler's claims are a little too radical for me to wrap my head around just yet.  Perhaps with time.  However, I have been convinced by the work of Landauer and Bennett that information plays a central role in the understanding of the 2nd Law.   It is part of the reason why I'm not satisfied with the "proofs" of the 2nd Law from stat mech that I've looked at so far.  But there are many of them, and I'm probably not in a position to assess all of them.

Comment: Worth noting that although quantum field theory provides a general *framework* for expressing different forces as different quantum fields, it does not actually "unify" them in the sense meant by physicists--unification refers to the idea that high enough energies, what previously looked like two diff. field theories actually turn out to be aspects of a *single* quantum field. This sort of unification has already been achieved for the electromagnetic and weak nuclear forces, which unite as "electroweak theory", but so far neither the strong nuclear force or gravity have been united this way.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: It's the electroweak force, described by Quantum Electro Dynamics. Unification with the strong force in an elctronuclear force hasn't been experimentally tested, but the models make sense and are ready to be tested. Gravity is in a different category, where we know only that it can't be unified using current quantum tools

Comment: My understanding is that quantum electrodynamics does not deal with the weak force, electroweak theory is a distinct quantum field theory (see the last paragraph of the ['history' section of the QED article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#History) which says QED served as a model for later quantum field theories including electroweak theory). And I think there are many proposed unifications of electroweak with strong (known as Grand Unified Theories or GUTs), there aren't strong theoretical arguments for thinking one specific proposal (if any) is most likely correct.

Answer (score 1):

When reductionists say that everything reduces to physics, they mean that everything can ultimately be explained by the fundamental laws of the physical world, whatever those are.

We happen to have at the moment a small set of independent but complementary theories which still have a few holes and sometimes conflict, but that is irrelevant. What matters is that the study of the physical world and the improvement of those theories is, ultimately, the only game in town.

Comment: I guess my main complaint is that the supposed _ultimate explanation_ isn't much of an explanation for most things.  To recycle an example I used earlier, what could the hoped for theory of everything tell you about the motion of a spinning top that you don't already know from the classical theory? Seems like it would take quite a bit of doing to get from the ToE even to the idea of an approximately rigid macroscopic body.

Comment: Yes it does take quite a bit of doing. But to a reductionist, all that is a consequence of Nature's many layers of complex behaviour, each of which is an emergent property of stuff obeying the layer beneath. A top is an emergent property of its constituent atoms and electromagnetic fields, an atom of its constituent particles and the electroweak field, its nucleons of quarks and gluons. Kinematics is an emergent property of energetic physical objects, and so on and on. I do not accept it 100%, but it is the reductionist position.

Comment: Depending on how _emergent_ is interpreted, I'm a reductionist according to the account you gave.  I would think most everyone is who does not believe in a separate Mind stuff.  I accept something like physical determinism.  I just don't think it follows that all facts reduce to the most basic physical facts in any meaningful sense.   Actually I think most facts of interest to us don't reduce to physics, even though in some (useless) sense everything is physically determined.  So it seems that reductionists must mean something extra, or they just aren't being careful with their words.